# "Не" или "ни" в предложении "Это всё — не/ни культ, не/ни фетиш, не/ни каприз от изобилья"?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, не-или-ни

Такая строка: *"Это всё — не культ, не фетиш, не каприз от изобилья".* Правильно ли я вписал частицу "не"? Или всё же "ни"?

Answer (score 3):

**Это всё — не культ, не фетиш, не каприз от изобилия.**

В этой конструкции по смыслу подразумевается **противопоставление**, оно должно быть ясным из контекста. Усилительного значения, характерного для частицы НИ, в этом предложении нет.